# How to display the label ( text) value dynamically based on combo box selection value ( List box) in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am new to tkinter application. The below code is working fine. Please help how to implement mentioned features.

1. The dynamic value should be displayed above clear button or below the combo box ( Used pack is bottom )- Now working
2. Clear the label value on combo box selection.

   ```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import *
    from datetime import datetime
    # root window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("500x350")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.title('Test')
    # Log Generator in frame
    Generator = tk.Frame(root)
    Generator.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill='x', expand=True)

    def clear():
        combo.set('')

    # Function to print the index of selected option
    # in Combobox
    def get_log_file_name(*arg):
        date_Value = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%I%M%S")
        output_file_name_value = "Log_"+date_Value
        if var.get() == "apple":
                Label(Generator, text="The value at index: "+output_file_name_value+".txt", font=('Helvetica 12')).pack()
        else:
                Label(Generator, text="The value at index: "+output_file_name_value+".html", font=('Helvetica 12')).pack()

    # Define Tuple of months
    months = ('apple','banana')

    # Create a Combobox widget

    label = ttk.Label(Generator, text="Selection_Option:",font=('Helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
    label.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
    var = StringVar()
    combo = ttk.Combobox(Generator, textvariable=var)
    combo['values'] = months
    combo['state'] = 'readonly'
    combo.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

    # Set the tracing for the given variable
    var.trace('w', get_log_file_name)

    # Create a button to clear the selected combobox 
    # text value
    button = Button(Generator, text="Clear", command=clear)
    button.pack(side=left)

    # Make infinite loop for displaying app on 
    # the screen
    Generator.mainloop()
   ```

[image]

Comment: You need to create the value label once outside the function and use `.config(text=...)` to update its text inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The dynamic value should be displayed above clear button

The second `label` could be outside of `get_log_file_name()` function.

And also `configure` inside function. So you don't do duplicate `Label` widget, naming `Label2`

Also the `pack()` must be split to prevent an error.

To clear `Label2` use `.configure(text='')`

We will be using `ttk`. So don't do this `from tkinter import *`

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x350")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('Test')
 
Generator = tk.Frame(root)
Generator.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill='x', expand=True)

def clear():
    label2.configure(text='')

 
def get_log_file_name(*arg):
    date_Value = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%I%M%S")
    output_file_name_value = "Log_"+date_Value
    if var.get() == "apple":
        label2.configure(text="The value at index: "+output_file_name_value+".txt", font=('Helvetica 12')) 
    else:
        label2.configure(text="The value at index: "+output_file_name_value+".html", font=('Helvetica 12'))

# Define Tuple of months
months = ('apple','banana')

# Create a Combobox widget
label2 = ttk.Label(Generator)
label2.pack()

label = ttk.Label(Generator, text="Selection_Option:",font=('Helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
label.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

var = tk.StringVar()
combo = ttk.Combobox(Generator, textvariable=var)
combo['values'] = months
combo['state'] = 'readonly'
combo.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

# Set the tracing for the given variable
var.trace('w', get_log_file_name)

# Create a button to clear the selected combobox 
# text value
button = ttk.Button(Generator, text="Clear", command=clear)
button.pack(side='left')

# Make infinite loop for displaying app on 
# the screen
Generator.mainloop()
```

Screenshot for apple:

[image]

Screenshot for banana:

[image]

Screenshot to clear `Label2`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Clear the label value on combo box selection.

You need to capture the ComboboxSelect event to do that and the function to execute if captured the function should be like this

What you want to do here, is to capture the combobox event, and then, do the label configuration when capturing it.

Here is the code to do the thing, and you can add your own code:

```py
def comboboxEventCapture(e=None):
    label.configure(text='')
    # Your code after resetting variables!
```

Here's the event capturing part

```py
combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelect>>", comboboxEventCapture)
```

You can name the function whatever you want though.

Note that the argument e is needed because if the event is captured, the event itself is passed as a parameter into the function, that is of no use here (unless you are going to do something with it, then use `e.objname`)